# Redirect visitor to the same url that he/she write without database

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have 2 websites let says (example1.com and example2.com).

if the visitor write in the url any number for example (example1.com/123456) i want it to re-directed to (example2.com/123456) so the domain only replaced not the numbers the visitor written.

i need that happen using htaccess file or any simple methods without database or save any data because i have only HTML pages, and its hard to me to do it because i am still learning.

Comment: What have you tried? Should be able to use standard redirect in htaccess for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a redirection on protocol level. That is possible with all usual http server's, the exact solution depends on *which* http server you are using to serve the domain "example1.com".

Since you tagged your question `.htaccess` and `mod-rewrite` I assume that you are using the apache http server. If so you can implement a rule like that one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ https://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect all requests to `example1.com` that use a path that consists only of digits to the second domain while preserving the requested path. An external redirection will get performed using a http status 301 ("moved permanently") as a response to the first request to `example1.com`.

If *both* domains are served by the same http server and you do *not* have setup separate virtual hosts you probably have to add a condition to that to make sure the rule only gets applied to requests to the first domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?\.example1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ https://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Preferably such a general redirection rule should get implemented in the central http server's host configuration responsible for serving `example1.com`. If you do *not* have access to that you can indeed use a *distributed* configuration file instead, often called ".htaccess". If so you need to enable that feature beforehand using the `AllowOverride` directive. The configuration file needs to be located in the hosts top level `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder and it needs to be readable for the http server process.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. here is another example.
my website is (example.com) if visitor write a numbers after / it should re-direct it to this url whatsapp://send?phone= (here is the numbers) so if its opened from phone it will open whatsapp chat.

Comment: @Savior Let's keep things separate: what you now raise here (`whatsapp://send?phone=`) is a completely different topic. Such a URL _mighty_ work, but that is out of your control. It depends on the settings the user on the client side chose. And it has absolutely nothing to do with request rewriting which is what your question was about.

Comment: @Savior Your question itself was about a redirection between web servers using the https protocol. That is what I answered to . If you claim "doesn't work" then please explain what that means _exactly_ . What happens for requests? What do you see in the browser? In the browser's networking console`In the http server's error log file? Without that it is impossible to offer further help.

Comment: @Savior Sorry, I just saw that there was a typo in the answer. I fixed it. Please try again with the fixed version in the answer. And report back what happens if you test using a fresh, anonymous browser window.

Comment: i am sorry i didn't mean its not work as a code, i meant it didn't work as i was hope. let say that you visit (example.com) and you write your phone number after the / the website should re-direct you to (whatsapp://send?phone=xxx) xxx is your phone number so whatsapp chat will open normally, also you can use this (https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=). thank you so much for your great help.

Comment: @Savior OK, I begin to understand what you actually want to do. Although that is indeed something completely different than what you asked in the question above. You apparently miss understand what `whatsapp://send?phone=xxx` actually is. The `whatsapp://` part in there is _not_ a domain (you mention `example2.com` as a domain in your question). Instead it is a _protocol scheme_ inside the URL, so the equivalent to the `https://` in web URLs. The apache rewriting module is unable to redirect to such a URL, it can only redirect to http or https URLs, so to _web_ URLs.

Comment: @Savior You might be able to achieve something similar using client side logic (so `javascript`). For that you can simply use a form inside your web page. You _might_ be able to implement something along the lines you phrase ("types a number inside the URL bar of the browser") if you use a scheme like that: `https://example.com/#123456` (note the `#`), you'd have to implement a logic in javascript that evaluates that string following that hash tag. But that has absolutely nothing to do with rewriting inside apache, so with a ".htaccess" styile file.

Comment: @Savior And once more, since you apparently missed that detail I mentioned above: even if you succeed in changing the URL that way your solution won't work in a reliable manner. Because whether a URL in the form you suggest (`whatsapp://send?phone=xxx`) actually works or has the desired effect on the client side is completely up to the settings chosen in the clients browser. You have no control over that. And the default setting _won't_ do what you expect.

Comment: @Savior Long store short: I doubt it is actually possible or sense making to implement what you have in mind. Sorry.

Comment: i really appreciate your great help and i understand now, but i didn't know how to explain the question. look what if i use this `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=` insead of a protocol `whatsapp://send?phone=` do you think that may work ? for example: visitor write a phone number after / on the domain let say `example.com/123456789` the htaccess re-direct all of it to `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123456789`.

Comment: so what i want is visitors can share my domain with thier phone number in social media and who click on the link with the phone number will re-directed to the whatsapp link to open the chat. i tried to edit your code but still facing issues.

Comment: i saw many websites do it using short links script but it's paid, and i don't have enough money so i just want simple way that i can start from it and maybe one day i can buy script for that.

Comment: @Savior You certainly can redirect requests to a URL under the domain `api.whatsapp.com`. Whether you are allowed to do that and what happens if you do that is something I cannot answer. I do not use Zuckerbergs evil products, sorry. But that is irrelevant for the technical aspect of redirection. What I posted above works. Again: you writing "but still facing issues" without being specific does not help. What does that mean?

Comment: @Savior You also write "i saw many websites do it" ... What does "it" actually mean here? So far you now gave three different goals you are trying to achieve. So which one is "it"? Also I fail to understand what you actually mean by "who click on the link". So far you describe that users manually enter their number in a URL address bar. What does that have to do with a "link"? You need to be more precise. And I dare say you also need to really make up your mind what you actually want to achieve, _precisely_ ...

Comment: i am sorry for the inconvenience, i used your code his one `RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` result is `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=/123456789` how i remove the / that before the number ? only / before the number i want to remove it from the result.

Comment: Have you ever thought about actually reading the documentation of the tools you use? No? Why not? What you describe is well documented. Here is the answer: `RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$1 [R=301,L]`. I suggest you start reading here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I understand that you are new in this field. There is no reason to be sorry for anything. But what I expect is that you read the documentation. And that you take care to get your questions clear before posting them.

Comment: believe me i read too much about that, and i did the code with one issue i did not know that i have to remove `%{REQUEST_URI}` i put it like this `$1%{REQUEST_URI}` that why i said i facing issues because i tried to modify it many times in wrong way. anyway now its worked perfect and thank you very much i wouldn't do it without your help. all your notes has been saved in my mind for the future. thank you so much.

Comment: @Savior Glad I could be of help.

Comment: @Savior I hope you worked through the solution to actually understand _why_ and _how_ it works. _That_ is what you should take out of this question.